# Accordion working in Html but not PHP

Tags: php

i designed a html page with the Accordion and it worked well, but when i changed the extension to PHP, the accordion wasnt working well again, below is my code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: 100% for sure this is not because you "just" changed the file extension to PHP.  What is "not working"?

Comment: Did you change the extension back and it worked again?

Comment: Yes, when i changed it back it worked, i can add the accordion portion for u to see

Comment: perform a diff/comparison on the output

Comment: Are you attempting to run the file from a local disk or from a web server?

Comment: @philwinkle, im runningg it on a local disk

Comment: You need a web server to process PHP....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better create a new file on .php and copy there all the code, then close it. I have similar problems sometimes with images.